# Fluent NHibernate: Prevent class from being mapped

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I am sure it is a piece of cake, but I can't find it using google.
I need to EXCLUDE a single class from mapping. My current configuration is:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
      .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(c =>
                c.Is(@"Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;......")))
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.AutoMappings.Add(
                AutoPersistenceModel.MapEntitiesFromAssemblyOf<Person2>()
                        .Where(t => t.Namespace == "ExampleData.HumansTest")
                        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<PersonMappingOverrides>()
                        .ConventionDiscovery.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMappingOverrides>()
                        )
                     ).BuildConfiguration();
```

Works nice, so far... 
But I have some classes I don't want to map. Is there anything like:

PSEUDO CODE:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(c =>
                c.Is(@".......")))
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.AutoMappings.Add(
                AutoPersistenceModel.MapEntitiesFromAssemblyOf<Person2>()
                        .Where(t => t.Namespace == "ExampleData.HumansTest")
                        .DO_NOT_MAP_CLASS<UnfinishedClass>
                        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<PersonMappingOverrides>()
                        .ConventionDiscovery.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMappingOverrides>()
                        )
                     ).BuildConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd try

```
...
.Where(t => t.Namespace == "ExampleData.HumansTest"
           && t != typeof(UnfinishedClass))
...
```

Comment: Nice... Thanks, worked perfectly. And "Doh" from my side, could have seen it :-)